# How to turn a string into an attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a really simple command-based python script, and get commands from the terminal's input, but it's not detecting the value of the variable... I'm not good at explaining, so here's my code:

```py
a = 0
b = 0

class commands:
    def add():
        a = int(input("first number "))
        b = int(input("second number "))
        print(a + b)

commander = commands
cmd = input("what command ")
commander.cmd()
```

When I run it, it gives me an error saying `Exception has occurred: AttributeError
type object 'commands' has no attribute 'cmd'`
I'm still relatively new to Python, so sorry if it's something really obvious. Thank you, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: To create an instance of your `commands` class, you need to call it by using `commander = commands()` (note the parentheses at the end). It's also unclear how you expect the instance to have a `cmd` (or any other) attributes at all. What strings should be turned into attributes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you just have to do:

```
getattr(commander, cmd)()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code with `if-else` so that you can get your desired result:-

```
a = 0
b = 0

class commands:
    def add(self):
        a = int(input("first number "))
        b = int(input("second number "))
        print(a + b)

commander = commands()
cmd = input("what command ")
print(cmd)
if cmd == 'add':
   commander.add()
```

I hope it may help you.